# Firewall will not play ball

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-firewall

I'm running SQL Server 2008 Express on a windows 2012... or at least I'm trying to :)

My problem is that I have opened the ports I thought I needed but still I cant manage to connect to the database from Visual Studio. As proof I have a screenshot of my firewall settings:

[image]

Everything works fine if I turn the firewall off, but who wants that while connected to the internet?

So I wonder what the heck is wrong? Is that some arbitrary ports that gets blocked? Is that a feature on the server (maybe its the same for 2008?)

Large image: http://bildr.no/view/1280743

Comment: How are you connecting?  Is the server on a local box or remote to the Visual Studio installation?

Comment: I have VS running on my home, personal, work pc and the database on a 2nd computer. if i turn of the firewall eveything connects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Express typically installs as a named instance, which by default uses a dynamic port.  In most cases, it will use 1433 (but not always).  You may want to step through:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440(v=sql.100).aspx

and see if you can assign the service to a fixed port.

Comment: SUPER! Everything works! Assigned the port and it all flows perfectly! YAY